# How to check if a date string follows specific data format

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, momentjs

I have an app, user can specify their own data format, like 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'MM/dd/yy', etc.

Once I receive a date string, I need to validate if the date string is valid for the given format.

I tried to use `moment(dataString, dateFormat).isValid()`, but looks it does not do the work

For dateString: `01/01/20`
with  dateFormat `MM/dd/yyyy`, expect `false`

with  dataFormat `MM/dd/yy`, expect `true`

`moment('01/01/2020', 'MM/dd/yy').isValid()`         --- expect: false, actual: true

`moment('01/02/2020', 'MM/dd/yyyy', true).isValid()`   --- expect: true,  actual: false

What I can use to achieve this?

Comment: If you can, consider using another date library as [Moment.js is maintenance-only mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: Please not that moment parsing tokens are case sensitive, so, for example, there is no lowercase `yyyy`, you should use `YYYY` instead. Anyway using [Strict Mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) may help you achieve what you need.

Answer (score 2):

you have to capitalize DD and supply true in the 3rd parameter, to enable strict parsing

```js
console.log(moment('This string includes a date with slashes 01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY').isValid())
console.log(moment('This string does not include a date with slashes', 'MM/DD/YYYY').isValid())
console.log(moment('01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY', true).isValid())
console.log(moment('01/01/2020', 'MM/dd/YYYY', true).isValid())
console.log(moment('01/01/20', 'MM/dd/YYYY', true).isValid())
console.log(moment('01/01/20', 'MM/DD/YY', true).isValid())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```